# Problem On Class Imbalanced Data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, class-imbalance

I am getting an F-Score of 0.99 on the `train_test_split` data, but only getting 0.40 for a competition's test data. I am oversampling with random forest (after oversampling both of the classes have 95469 data). Before oversampling the data was 0 - 95469 and 1 - 193 respectively.

Comment: you did the oversampling *after* splitting your train/test data right? otherwise you would have the same instances in the training and test set, so your evaluation of 0.99 would be wrong. Do you have the detail of the errors on the test data? i.e. confusion matrix showing which instances are misclassified. That could help you tune your training in the right direction.

Comment: I used oversampling first then train-test-split  here is the confusion matrix array([[9483,   28],
       [  46, 9537]])

Comment: I think you should separate your training and test data before doing oversampling, because otherwise your test set contains instances created artificially which are very similar to the ones in your training set, that's why your first F-score is (artificially) very high.

Comment: The confusion matrix you gave in your comment looks like the one on your oversampled dataset because the classes are balanced and it corresponds to a 99% performance. It would be much more useful to get the confusion matrix on the real test set, or a non-oversampled validation set.